# CA2227 With Dictionary what is the fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary, fxcop

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
```

With the above line of code I am getting a style cop error, CA2227 Collection properties should be read only.

Is there some way I can move past this error without adding a Stylecop suppression or having to create my own read-only dictionary class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you just need to remove the "set" keyword. Something like this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get { return this.data; } }
```

Often, you don't need to reassign a collection, but can instead just clear the existing one. 
I guess that's where this warning comes from. The above sample is the approach I am using most of the time.

Comment: thanks. i did try something similar to that but not quite, having one of those days!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure but the following might suppress the error:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; private set; }
```

To be honest, it is silly to hinder your development due to someone's subjective idea of style (aka StyleCop and FxCop).

Comment: Disagree. Stylecop and FxCop are great. It's just stupid to fix all violations of FxCop (fixing all stylecop rules that are chosen by the development team is, in the other hand, a good idea), but understanding produced warnings is **always** a good idea.

Comment: I did try this but I got CA1811: set appears to have no upstream public or protected callers. Oh, how I love Style/Fx Cop!

Comment: @ken2k: That is **your** opinion. Mine is different. Compiler warnings are always good though. Makes no point to have anything less than Warning Level 4.

Comment: @Tyler: Assign to `Data` in the constructor.

Comment: @leppie Of course it's **my** opinion. That's why I said "disagree", not "you're wrong", and why I didn't downvoted your answer. But I strongly disagree, I think Stylecop should always be used, especially for a team work (not all developers have the same style and having an homogeneous code is _crucial_ when it's time to debug), and code analysis will help a lot finding potential critical issues (your C# compiler won't tell you 50% of the `IDisposable` implementations of your colleagues are poorly written)...

Comment: @leppie BTW, FxCop (code analysis) as nothing to do with _style_. It's about _design, portability, maintainability, performance, reliability, security_...etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a code analysis (previously named FxCop) warning, not StyleCop.
And this is CA2227, not CA1227.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that is pretty self-explanatory about the problem.

Try the following (**private** setter) to fix it:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that CA2227 asks you to provide a readonly `Dictionary<,>`. Rather StyleCop complains that you can set the Dictionary directly. You should remove the setter and/or make it private to get rid of the warning. In addition your class may provide your own `Add` and `Clear` methods. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327%28VS.80%29.aspx for details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I find with this particular recommendation/warning is that devs that "fix it" often end up coding often needless copies rather than using a reference to the original collection.  For example, I have the following line:

```
myThing.Items = GetItems();
```

And the dev fixes it with:

```
var items = GetItems();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    myThing.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Imagine GetItems() returns a collection of a million items.  How can this be a good thing?  I find Microsofts statement of "Do not exclude a warning from this rule." in MSDN to be a little strong!